# How to transform a blocking code into a reactive code

Tags: spring-webflux, reactive

I looking for a good way to code this:

```
MyCloudDTO saveInCloud(MyCloudDTO dto) {
   //sync http call :-(
   return cloudService.save(dto);
}

MyData saveInDb(MyData data) {
   //database call 
   return repository.save(data);
}

MyDTO save(MyDTO dto) {
   MyCloudDTO cloudDTO = mapper.map(dto);
   dto.setCloudId(saveInCloud(dto).getId());
   MyData data = mapper2.map(dto);
   dto.setDbId(saveInDb(data).getId());
   return dto;
}
```

With Spring WebFlux and Monos.

The main problem here is that I want to keep the base dto during all the process because the mappers map only the properies they need and leave the the rest.

I found a way to do that but I'm not sure that's the correct/best way to do:

```
Mono<MyCloudDTO> saveInCloud(MyCloudDTO dto) {
   return reactiveCloudService.save(dto);
}

Mono<MyData> saveInDb(MyData data) {
   return reactiveRepository.save(data);
}

Mono<MyDTO> save(MyDTO dto) {

    Mono<MyDTO> baseMono = Mono.just(dto);

    Mono<MyCloudDTO> saveCloudMono = Mono.just(dto)
            .map(mapper::map)
            .flatMap(this::saveInCloud);

    Mono<MyDTO> mergeAfterCloudSave = Mono.zip(
            baseMono,
            saveCloudMono,
            (base, cloudDto) -> base.idCloud(cloudDto.getId())); //the setter return this


    Mono<MyData> saveDbMono = mergeAfterCloudSave
            .map(mapper2::map)
            .flatMap(this::saveInCloud);


    Mono<MyDTO> mergeAfterDbSave = Mono.zip(
            mergeAfterCloudSave,
            saveDbMono,
            (base, dbData) -> base.idDb(data.getId())); //the setter return this


    return mergeAfterDbSave;
}
```

Thank you very much!

Saveriu

Comment: using reactive infrastructure in an app should go bottoms up: starting with HTTP client, the datastore and then exposing those at the web layer. you'll get zero benefit (actually, probably worse performance than regular blocking IO) by wrapping those with Monos.

Comment: Hello,
Yes you're right, I'm changing all the stack (DB drivers and the Spring Boot2 Webflux stack).